# Switch GtkVboxes on one GtkWindow in ARM

Tags: gtk

Everybody, Hello.

I'm new to gtk+ and want to ask a newbie question.

I want make a software of gtk2.10 in arm. My code is followed.

```
GtkWidget *windowmain = NULL;

GtkWidget *thebox = NULL;

GtkWidget *boxmain = NULL;

GtkWidget *boxtreeviewlist = NULL;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

    boxmain = createmain();
    thebox = boxmain;
    boxtreeviewlist = createtreeviewlist();

    g_object_ref_sink(boxmain);
    g_object_ref_sink(boxtreeviewlist);

    windowmain = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    gtk_window_set_position(GTK_WINDOW(windowmain), GTK_WIN_POS_CENTER);
    gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(windowmain), WINDOW_DEFAULT_WIDTH_SIZE, WINDOW_DEFAULT_HEIGTH_SIZE);
    g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(windowmain), "delete_event", G_CALLBACK(on_delete_event), NULL);

    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(windowmain), boxmain);

    gtk_widget_show_all(windowmain);

    gtk_main();

    return TRUE;
}

GtkWidget* createmain()

{
    GtkWidget *box = NULL;

    GtkWidget *framestatus = NULL;

    GtkWidget *framebutton = NULL;

    GtkWidget *scroll = NULL;

    GtkWidget *textview = NULL;


    box = gtk_vbox_new(FALSE, 10);

    framestatus = create_frame_status(TRUE, 0);
    gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(box), framestatus, FALSE, TRUE, 0);

    scroll = gtk_scrolled_window_new(NULL, NULL);
    gtk_scrolled_window_set_policy(GTK_SCROLLED_WINDOW(scroll), GTK_POLICY_AUTOMATIC, GTK_POLICY_AUTOMATIC);
    gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(box), scroll, TRUE, TRUE, 0);

    textview = gtk_text_view_new();
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(scroll), textview);

    framebutton = main_create_button_box(GTK_BUTTONBOX_EDGE, "");
    gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(box), framebutton, FALSE, TRUE, 0);

    return box;
}

GtkWidget* createtreeviewlist()

{

    GtkWidget *box = NULL;

    GtkWidget *framebutton = NULL;

    GtkCellRenderer*   renderer = NULL;

    GtkTreeViewColumn* column = NULL;


    box = gtk_vbox_new(FALSE, 0);

    list_store = gtk_list_store_new(STANDARD_LIST_COLUMNS, GDK_TYPE_PIXBUF, G_TYPE_STRING, G_TYPE_STRING, G_TYPE_STRING);

    treeview = gtk_tree_view_new_with_model(GTK_TREE_MODEL(list_store));
    gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(box), treeview, TRUE, TRUE, 0);

    framebutton = treeviewlist_create_button_box(GTK_BUTTONBOX_EDGE, "");
    gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(box), framebutton, FALSE, TRUE, 0);

    return box;
}

void show_box(GtkWidget *box)

{

    gtk_container_remove(GTK_CONTAINER(windowmain), thebox);

    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(windowmain), box);

    thebox = box;

    gtk_widget_show_all(windowmain);

}
```

In the Ubuntu10.0.04， it's work well. Use X11.

But in the arm, when show boxmain, in other words，use (show_box) to switch boxtreeviewlist to boxmain,  in the windowmain I can look image of boxtreeviewlist.   Use Directfb.

Can anybody help me? Thanks.

Comment: It is a pain in the ass to work using sample code that doesn't compile. Then, it's hard to guess from what you say what you want, and what you get. I've compiled your code, but it doesn't show how you use your `show_box`, and I don't own a crystal ball to guess what how you're doing things...

Answer (score 0):

You never add `boxtreeviewlist` to a container. Use a `GtkVBox` or `GtkHBox` as intermediate container to add two items to a single parent.

Then you can just use `gtk_widget_set_visible()` to change visibility of the two items.

Comment: I try it. But it is still.

Comment: I feel odd that it work well in Ubuntu10.04(X11), but in Directfb(1.1.1) it works matter.

Comment: Is my gtk(2.10.12) version is old?Is my Directfb(1.1.1) version is old?  thank you.

Comment: GTK 2.10 is old, but it's widely used in embedded because it's light. It's the last version before cairo was internally used for graphics stuff if I remember well.